# How to hide an aggressive crawler?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I'm planning to crawl a specific site. I have 3000 specific pages that I want to crawl once every few months. I've created a crawler, but I don't want to be banned from the site.

Is there a way to reduce the aggressiveness of the crawler or hide it in some way so not to be "noticed" or cause issues for the provider/website that I'm crawling?

A delay is possible, but if I set it to random 10-30 second delay per page then it will take forever.

ANy tips or guidelines to make an acceptable crawler?

Comment: You should respect `robots.txt` in any case.

Comment: Maybe the next question here will be "How do I detect unwanted aggressive crawlers on my site?"

Comment: 3000 * 30 is 90000 seconds which is 25 hours. Unless you want to crawl the site more than every other week it hardly takes forever...

Comment: In your particular case, could you discuss this with the site in question? Some sites are fine with this, others not. Check also to see if they have an API using which their content may be obtained legitimately. Also, if you can give more specific details here about the site (if not the actual site name) then people here will offer a view as to whether it is acceptable crawler behaviour (generally taking someone else's content just to display adverts with it is unacceptable, for example).

Comment: @EmilH: You are right, I forgot to calculate to hours - I therefore got around 60 days ;)

24 hours are more than doable... Now I just need to make a ajax script or something that can run this is the browser over the next couple of days or weeks - thx

Answer (score 1):

One more solution is to use **PROXY server provider** (*like [this one](http://seo-proxies.com) for example*) and rotate IP address every *X* requests. This particular provider has an *API* to retrieve IPs on the fly. *cURL* can be used for this purpose easily if speaking about *PHP*.

This technique works in most cases, but it requires a bit more planning and tuning. Anyway you will face some limitations. It can be as time issue as well as the number of requests per period what is almost the same issue as time ones. Or you will need more proxy servers to satisfy your time requirements.

And read attentively *TOS* of providers. This particular provider doesn't allow you to be banned by Google and some other sites. Otherwise your account will be banned also.

Answer (score 0):

"Acceptable" is a relative term. Some site owners have enough processing power and bandwidth that they don't think scanning 3000 pages per hour is "aggressive". Some site owners struggle for bandwidth or processing power and can't keep up with 3000 page reads per day.

If you want to read pages and get current contents, then you must read the pages. There's no shortcut to that.